# How to display a button in dependency of the state of a directive

Tags: angularjs

Given the following data which consists of an array of elements, that each have a title and a text:

```
[
    {
        title: 'title1',
        text: 'text1'
    },
    {
        title: 'title2',
        text: 'text2'
    }
]
```

Each entry of the array should be displayed as a list item using ng-repeat. Whereas each item makes use of contenteditable in order to make these fields editable.

I am using a directive to make the elements editable

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      function read() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
      }

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
      };

      element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
        scope.$apply(read);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This is the view which makes use of the contenteditable directive

```
<div ng-repeat = "entry in contentEditables.entries">
        <span contenteditable ng-model="entry.title"></span>
        <span contenteditable ng-model="entry.text"></span>
        <button ng-if="howToQueryIfOneOfTheContentEditablesHasBeenEdited?">save</button>
</div>
```

Each row should have a "save" button, which should be only displayed if one or both contenteditable elements of that row have been changed. I am able to track whether the contenteditable directive has changed by giving it its own scope, however I have not been able to find a way to display the save button only when the elements of that row have been changed.

How would one query the directive from within the view? Is there a better way to do something like this?

Plunker can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/E8ZC8zwGlO0AjsOoWTss?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple controller to handle that:

```
app.controller('EditableController', ['$scope', function(scope) {

  var initial = {};
  angular.copy(scope.entry, initial);

  scope.edited = function(val) {
    return !angular.equals(val, initial);
  };

}]);
```

And to initialize that controller:

```
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="ContentEditableController as contentEditables">
      <div ng-repeat = "entry in contentEditables.entries" ng-controller="EditableController">
        <span contenteditable ng-model="entry.title"></span>
        <span contenteditable ng-model="entry.text"></span>
        <button ng-if="edited(entry)">save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Plunker can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/E8ZC8zwGlO0AjsOoWTss?p=preview